# Scala and akka switch to mutable data collection in this case?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka, immutability

It dawned on me that it really isn't too hard to write functionally, so I decided to refactor some of my work an remove mutable collections from my code. The loc's just melt away. Now I am at a point where I have a Seq representing a collection of actors being supervised, each time one is done I need to remove it from the sequence. I guess functionally you would create a new seq and do a akka become with the new sequence.

```
def shepherd(categories: Seq[ActorRef]) : Receive = {
  case ForumCrawler.Done() => {
    val new_categories = categories.filter(a => a != sender)
    if(new_categories.size == 0) {
      println("all done")
      system.shutdown()
    }
   context.become(shepherd(new_categories))
}
```

When the actor sequence is in the 10k region is this still a viable approach ? Does scala somehow mutate the sequences behind the scenes or am I going to be getting a full set to set copy ?

This kinda makes me feel like [select did back in the day](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select), only probably worse =D

Comment: protip: never use size == 0, always use isEmpty

Comment: If these ForumCrawlers are the only children of the actor in question then you might as well use `context.children` and save yourself the trouble ;-)

Comment: Roland, Yeah I discovered that earlier =D

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some calculations for a 10K sequence. The worst case scenario is if the selected ActorRef is always last. Then you would have to do `10000+9999+...+2+1` iterations, or `(10000*10001)/2 = 50 005 000`. The general formula for calculating this:

[image: Formula]

I don't think you want to do worst-case 50 million iterations :). Let's use a different datastructure, it's always good to take a look at the [performance characteristics of Scala collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html). The only immutable structure that has a constant remove complexity is `HashSet` and `HashMap`. We don't have key value pairs so `HashSet` should suffice. Since this is in an Actor you could potentially use mutable structures as it's guaranteed to be run on a single thread, so an other option would be `WeakHashMap`.

So rewriting your solution using `HashSet`:

```
def shepherd(categories: HashSet[ActorRef]) : Receive = {
  case ForumCrawler.Done() =>
    val newCategories = categories - sender
    if(newCategories.size == 0) {
      println("all done")
      system.shutdown()
    }
    context.become(shepherd(newCategories))
}
```

Comment: Heya, I wasn't concerned with the add/removed complexity but the immutable and functional style of working with sequences. Does scala really create a copy on each alteration of an immutable data structure ?

Comment: Yes it does, hence it's immutability. All Scala immutable collection operations return a new copy of themselves. In this case if it's an actor it's guaranteed to be run one a single thread at once, so you could use mutable data structures. I would use a mutable HashSet here, because it makes sense and would simplify thing and increase performance. Just make sure not to pass the mutable collection to the outside and everything should be okay.